# render ASP.NET MVC Partial View in EXT.NET Formpanel container or Items collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ext.net

how can i render `ASP.NET MVC` Partial View in `EXT.NET` Formpanel container or Items collection

Comment: show us what have you tried

Comment: i'm using Ext.NET with ASP.NET MVC 4.while trying to add `@Html.Partial("viewname") inside Ext.NET Containers Items collection vs giving error that cannont convert from System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString to Ext.Net.AbstractComponent

Comment: he means edit the question and include the code that didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Html.X().Panel()

.TabMenuHidden(true)

.Title("Alt Tetkikler")

.ItemsFromPartial("AltTetkiklerPartial")

Comment: Can you provide some explanation along with your answer. It will be useful to understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

Just set your Item to the RenderPartial:

```
.Items(i => Html.RenderPartial("SharedView", ModelForView)
```